# Объясните, что не так с побитовым умножение

Tags: c

Моя функция

```
bool compare(char* IP, char* mask){
     int c;
     int imask = 0;     
     int iIP = 0;

     while(((c = *IP++) != '.') && (c != '\0')){
          iIP += (c - '0')*10;            
     }            
     iIP /= 10;

     while(((c = *mask++) != '.') && (c != '\0')){
          imask += (c - '0')*10;            
     }            
     imask /= 10;
     if(c == '\0') return (imask & iIP) == iIP ? true: false ;

     if( (imask & iIP) == iIP ) compare(IP, mask);  
     else return false;    
}
```

Не пойму, выводит всё время истину, хотя явно октет маски с октетом айпи истинно не умножаются, подскажите, может ошибка в преобразовании?

Answer (score 6):

Не особо вникая, вот эта строчка уж очень подозрительная:

```
if( (imask & iIP) == iIP ) compare(IP, mask);
```

Может, имелось в виду:

```
if( (imask & iIP) == iIP ) return compare(IP, mask);
```

Comment: Блин, огромное спасибо, вся фигня в рекурсии, и правда, благодарю

Answer (score 3):

Тут уже ответили про ошибку, но я бы еще дополнил про недочеты. Во-первых, этот цикл

```
while(((c = *IP++) != '.') && (c != '\0')){
      iIP += (c - '0')*10;            
 }            
 iIP /= 10;
```

надо переписать так:

```
while( (c = *IP++) && c != '.' ) {
{
    iIP *= 10;
    iIP += c - '0';
}
```

Во-вторых, конструкция вида cond? true : false абсолютно бессмысленна, ее можно заменить просто на cond. В-третьих, Вы используете рекурсию, чтобы избежать повторения кода, но не там Вы ищете нарушение принципа DRY, ох не там... А два одинаковых цикла Вас не смущают?

Я бы переписал совершенно по-иному:

```
unsigned long ip2ulong(const char* str)
{
    unsigned long ip = 0;
    unsigned long octet = 0;

    while( *str ) {
        if( *str == '.' ) {
            ip <<= 8;
            ip += octet;
            octet = 0;
        } else {
            octet *= 10;
            octet += *str - '0';
        }
        ++str;
    }
    return ip;
}
```

И теперь, если уж очень надо:

```
bool compare(const char* str_ip, const char* str_mask)
{
    unsigned long ip = ip2ulong(str_ip);
    unsigned long mask = ip2ulong(str_mask);
    return (mask &= ip) == ip;
}
```

Но мне такой подход не нравится уже потому, что Ваша функция занимается двумя вещами: изменением представления данных и операцией над ними. Нарушаются принцип единственности ответственности и принцип одного уровня абстракции. В реальном приложении IP будет один раз переведен из строкового вида в числовой, и потом уже все операции будут над числами.

Соответственно, я бы переписал все это еще раз. Функция compare принимала бы два параметра типа unsigned long, а функция ip2ulong теперь может не бояться попортить строки, так что в ней можно использовать библиотечные strtok и atol. Но это уж Вы сами...

Comment: Благодарю, я с принципами DRY и абстракции не знаком, но теперь почитаю, ваш ответ был весьма полезным, спасибо

Comment: Принципы программирования - http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Антипаттерн - http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD

Разработка через тестирование - http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5